# Displaying API xml data on laravel 4 blade view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, amazon-product-api, laravel-blade

I am developing a website where you search items from amazon product advertising api.
I have a search box on views/layouts/master.blade.php with the following code:

```
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'AmazonAPI/api.php', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
        {{ Form::text('itemsearch', 'Search ...', ) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Search') }}
```

The form is posting to an api file with the following code:

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['booksearch'])) {
            /* Example usage of the Amazon Product Advertising API */
            include("amazon_api_class.php");

            $obj = new AmazonProductAPI();
            $result ='' ;
            try
            {
                $result = $obj->searchProducts($_GET['booksearch'],
                                               AmazonProductAPI::DVD,
                                               "TITLE");
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

            print_r($result->Items);


    ?>
```

After searching you are navigated to the file and it displays a valid xml data from amazon. But as you can see, The api file is a php file in my public/assets/AmazonAPI folder hence I cant extend my layouts when styling the xml.
Please let me know how I should include my API code in a views/searches/index.blade.php blade view such that I can extend a layout on it like:

```
@extends('layouts.mylayout')

@section('content')
//the api code goes here
@stop
```

Also let me know the correct way I should open the form.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have just edited the question. Please let me know where you need clarification

Comment: First of why are you putting api codes in `public/assets` folder? Either you are unable to explain your problem properly or I'm unable to understand. As for my understanding,You can call this file in any of your controller function and return the views with the desired result.

Comment: I have my api codes in public/assets folder because I am unable to figure out how else to access them. Please explain to me how you can call it from a controller function and return a view with results. That would be the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will guide you to do this in a simple and more `Laravel` Way.
so you can create a folder `libraries` under `app` directory
and place your amazon api files in the `libraries` folder.

Now in your `composer.json` add `"app/your_amozon_api_library_folder_name"` in classmap , something like

```
"autoload": { 
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/your_amozon_api_library_folder_name",
```

Now dump your autoload using `composer dump-autoload or php composer.phar dump-autoload`
Now you amozon api's are loaded for global use.

Suppose you have a HomeController with search method, now put you api codes in search method,

```
public function search(){
  if(isset($_GET['booksearch'])) {
        /* Example usage of the Amazon Product Advertising API */
        //include("amazon_api_class.php"); no need to include

        $obj = new AmazonProductAPI();
        $result ='' ;
        try
        {
            $result = $obj->searchProducts($_GET['booksearch'],
                                           AmazonProductAPI::DVD,
                                           "TITLE");
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        //print_r($result->Items);
        return View::make('your view name')->with('items',$result->Items);
 }
}
```